# Счетчик на java

Tags: html, php, javascript

Допустим у меня есть какое то число на странице, и я хочу, чтобы оно каждую секунду оно уменьшалось на 1 и, когда будет 0, обновить станицу.
(Стандартный счетчик с выводом на экран в определенном месте)
Число присваивается на любую переменную.
(Возможно это просто для вас, но я с JS не знаком, поэтому прошу вашей помощи)
Число я выведу с помощью РНР

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    onload = function(){
         // инициализируем интервал
         setInterval(function(){
               // функция будет вызываться каждую секунду
               // выбираем наш "счетчик" див
               var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
               // получаем целочисленное значение его HTML'я
               var counterValue = parseInt(counter.innerHTML);
               if(counterValue) {
                   // если оно не 0 ( т.е. не является false )
                   --counterValue;
                   // уменьшаем на единицу
                   counter.innerHTML = counterValue;
                   // записываем в элемент
               }
               else {
                   // в противном случае
                   document.location.href = ''; // перезагружаем страницу
               }
         }, 1000);
    }

</script>

<div id="counter">100</div>
<!-- тут естественно можешь выводить любое int(>0) значение -->
```

Answer (score 0):

К примеру начальное значение счетчика было выведено средствами пхп вот так:

```
<div id="counter"><?php echo $init_count; ?></div>
```

Тогда в javascript:

```
var Counter = (function(){

    var
        private = {
            start : 0,
            timer : 0,
            interval : 1000,
            value : 0,

            // значения, которые можно изменить в клиентском коде:
            elemId : 'counter', // значение по умолчанию
            destination : 'http://yandex.ru', // значение по умолчанию
        },

        public = {

            init : function(options){
                if ( options.hasOwnProperty('destination') ) {
                   private.destination = options.destination;
                }
                if ( options.hasOwnProperty('elemId') ) {
                    private.elemId = options.elemId;
                }

                private.elem = document.getElementById(private.elemId);

                // начальное значение
                if ( options.hasOwnProperty('start') ) {
                    private.start = options.start;
                    private.elem.innerHTML = private.start;
                } else {
                    private.start = Number(private.elem.innerHTML)
                }

                // текущее значение равно начальному
                private.value = private.start;

                return public;
            },

            go : function() {
                private.timer = window.setInterval(function(){
                    if ( private.value ) {
                        public.countDown();
                    } else {
                        public.action();
                    }
                }, private.interval)
                return public;
            },

            countDown : function(){
                private.elem.innerHTML = --private.value;
            },

            action : function(){
                document.location.href = private.destination;
            }
        };

    return public;

})();

// Обработчик написан, его можно вынести в отдельный файл
// а ниже показано как его вызывать, использовать

Counter.init({
    elemId       : 'counter',
    destination  : 'http://google.com'
}).go();
```

Comment: зачем такие сложности ( private, public... )?

1. Это не только будет добавлять тормозов, но и память ест...
2. По стандарту такие слова являются зарезервированными
3. Универсальность кода -> 0

Comment: @timka_s - солидарен на 100%...

@Innuendo108 - вы о **kiss** слышали?

Причем по поводу памяти добавлю - ест на пустом месте...

Comment: Тормозов не добавляет, запустите в профиле в firebug'e. 
Это называется JavaScript Module Pattern, только в оригинальной версии все методы не разделены на публичные и приватные. а разделение делает его удобнее. я привык практически любую задачу писать в виде модуля, это добавляет расширяемости. (хотя конечно вряд ли простой счетчик в что-нибудь разрастётся, но всё же)
Зарезервированные слова - да, ну это не мешает мне сделать такие переменные.
@AlexWindHope, слышал. Если все свои задачи писать в виде модулей, то их можно повторно использовать где угодно. Про `DRY` слышали? =)

Comment: @timka_s, @AlexWindHope, хорошо, допустим счетчик и простая задача, не нужно вам её расширять. Но к примеру, позже вам понадобится вставить подобный счетчик в другую страницу, с другими элементами и с другой логикой действия. А потом ещё раз и в другую. Вам придётся изменять код, что часто - практически равноценно переписыванию кода. В моём же случае, один комментарий к модулю, который указывает какие методы он поддерживает, и модуль в отдельном файле. Чтобы встроить его в новую страницу - чуть изменить клиентский код (вызов). Всю логику счетчика можно вынести в вызов, и будет всё гибко зато.

Comment: Мне прийдется лишь изменить ID элемента.

Даже если бы пришлось переписать - 10 строчек не панацея, я ничего не имею против модулей, но однозначно что то что написали вы крайне излишне и не несет практического смысла по определению.

Ничего гибкого не заметил, по-моему очень даже наоборот.

То что вы привыкли не означает что это хорошо, по поводу зарезервированных слов - не столь принципиально но по хорошему хотя-бы в кавычки взять было бы неплохо.

Как по мне то никакой гибкости нет и пользы от такого усложнения я уж точно не вижу, вред да, а вот пользы - не заметил...

Comment: Редактировать код имплементации не есть хорошо. Лучше отделять то, что можно редактировать в клиентский код. Чтобы изменять только вызов.
Я соглашусь, что возможно это излишество для подобной задачи писать модуль. 
Вот простой пример: допустим помимо счетчика у нас ещё 9 разных интерактивных объектов на странице, которые вы напишите сплошным кодом, а я напишу для каждого модуль. Ваш клиентский код будет занимать 10*50 = 500 строк. Мой - 10*4 = 40 строк (только вызовы) + 500-700 строк самих модулей. Редактировать мой клиентский код будет удобнее, а редактируем мы как раз клиентский код.

Comment: Но признаюсь, тут нету правого и не правого. Все мы правы, а по этому поводу можно спорить веками, устраивать буйные религиозные войны. Надо искать золотую середину, что не всегда легко.

Я соглашусь, что для автора подойдет вариант пользователя AlexWindHope

Comment: Кто вам сказал, что если на странице будет 10 интерактивных объектов я буду писать сплошной код? 

Я буду писать расширяемый ООП код, буду использовать какой-то JS фреймворк, буду планировать структуру и разработку.

Вообще меня улыбнуло, вы судите о моем подходе к разработке в целом по примеру с таймером... Вам не кажется что это полный бред?

Comment: @Innuendo108, я не сказал, что код @AlexWindHope'а - хорош)

Коментарии были к вашему, как к принципу построения

1. Универсальность: задача таймера является универсальной, выже сделали очень узкопрофильную реализацию.По мне, так нужно делать некую сущность, которая подсчитывает кол-во вызовов своего метода, при этом вызывая переданный ей, и при неком пороговом значении - генерирует новое событие.
2. Тормоза ( условно ) у вас будут, т.к. если посмотрите снимок памяти -  у вас объектов будет примерно в 10 раз больше чем при прототипном подходе

Comment: при 10 интерактивных объектов схожего типа я буду использовать модульный подход, для одного таймера - я напишу 10 не замысловатых строчек кода...

Причем пока вы будуте парится над модульностю ( причем там где она абсолютно не нужна ) - я напишу в разы больше.

ПРимер с X и Y неуместен, я вообще поражаюсь вы сумели расстянуть 10-15 строчный код на 60 с лишним строк, при этом вы еще и пытаетесь это оправдать...

Кстати - даже если рассматривать приведенный вами пример как законченный модуль - всеравно код крайне излишен.